# How can I get a real IP address from DNS query in Swift?

Tags: swift, dns, ip-address

I want to get the IP address (like 192.168.0.1 or 87.12.56.50) from DNS query in Swift. I tried 100 times with 100 different methods ... Nothing helped me, so I'll have to ask for help.
This is my code so far:

```
let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,"subdomain.of.stackoverflow.com").takeUnretainedValue();
CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .Addresses, nil);
var success: Boolean = 0;
let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray;
if(addresses.count > 0){
   let theAddress = addresses[0] as NSData;
   println(theAddress);
}
```

OK ... These are the links for the code I tried to implement without success:
https://gist.github.com/mikeash/bca3a341db74221625f5
[How to perform DNS query on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000441/how-to-perform-dns-query-on-ios)
[Create an Array in Swift from an NSData Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516170/create-an-array-in-swift-from-an-nsdata-object)
[Does CFHostGetAddressing() support ipv6 DNS entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796142/does-cfhostgetaddressing-support-ipv6-dns-entries)
[Do a simple DNS lookup in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898001/do-a-simple-dns-lookup-in-swift)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your code retrieves the address as a "socket address" structure. 
`getnameinfo()` can be used to convert the address into a numerical IP string
(code recycled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627545/1187415,
now updated to **Swift 2**):

```
let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,"www.google.com").takeRetainedValue()
CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .Addresses, nil)
var success: DarwinBoolean = false
if let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success)?.takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray?,
    let theAddress = addresses.firstObject as? NSData {
    var hostname = [CChar](count: Int(NI_MAXHOST), repeatedValue: 0)
    if getnameinfo(UnsafePointer(theAddress.bytes), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
        &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
            if let numAddress = String.fromCString(hostname) {
                print(numAddress)
            }
    }
}
```

Output (example): `173.194.112.147`

Note also the usage of `takeRetainedValue()` in the first line, because 
`CFHostCreateWithName()` has "Create" in its name the therefore returns a (+1) retained
object.

---

**Update for Swift 3/Xcode 8:**

```
let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,"www.google.com" as CFString).takeRetainedValue()
CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .addresses, nil)
var success: DarwinBoolean = false
if let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success)?.takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray?,
    let theAddress = addresses.firstObject as? NSData {
    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
    if getnameinfo(theAddress.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
                   &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
        let numAddress = String(cString: hostname)
        print(numAddress)
    }
}
```

Or, to get *all* IP addresses for the host:

```
let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,"www.google.com" as CFString).takeRetainedValue()
CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .addresses, nil)
var success: DarwinBoolean = false
if let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success)?.takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray? {
    for case let theAddress as NSData in addresses {
        var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
        if getnameinfo(theAddress.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
                       &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
            let numAddress = String(cString: hostname)
            print(numAddress)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the man! I'm very new to Swift and believe me ... you've added only 5 line to my code, but I don't understant a word of it. So you saved me time. I wouldn not do this by myself! Thanx!

Comment: @ХристоАтанасов: So you should now read the documentation on getnameinfo() and all that stuff until you understand it :)

Comment: I've run into a problem. If the hostname string is, for example, `hello`, the program crashes saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Comment: Probably you have to make some validations if the host name is valid domain and use it if it is ..

Comment: @Matt: you have to add exclamation mark at "as!" in next statement let theAddress = addresses[0] as NSData;

Comment: I am sorry whose IP is it? google's ip or your device ip?

Comment: @Saty: This returns the IP address of the DNS name resolution, in this example the (first) IP address of "www.google.com".

Comment: @Matt: That *is* updated for Swift 2. I just double-checked that it still compiles with Xcode 7.2.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the contribution! When I use it I get the IPv6 address, anyway I can get the IPv4, what do I need to change?

Comment: @Kostas: The above code only extracts the IP address from the first element of the `addresses` array. I have added another variant which prints all IP addresses.

Comment: I just updated my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794997/convert-nsdata-to-sockaddr-struct-in-swift) for Swift 5. It uses `inet_ntop()` instead of `getnameinfo()`. However I'm not very informed about network programming — which one should be preferred and when? Perhaps one of these questions should be closed as duplicate of the other.

Comment: Upon further reading I think `getnameinfo` is better, so I'll close the other question.

Comment: The above returns IPv4 address for me, how can I adjust this so it returns the IPv6 address?

Comment: @BobTheCoder:  That code returns both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, if available. Perhaps your router/DNS server does not support IPv6?

Comment: @MartinR Maybe I am misunderstanding sorry, is there anyway I can get the IPv6 equivalent of the IPv4 address that is returned from this function?

Comment: @BobTheCoder: I am not sure if I understand you. Do you mean the [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses)? I am afraid that I can not help you with that.

Comment: @MartinR On mac in my terminal if I run `dig A +short apple.com` and `dig AAAA +short apple.com` I get the corresponding IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, I'm trying to figure out how to do the same in swift but am unsure exactly how.

Comment: @BobTheCoder: In fact I get two addresses (2620:149:af0::10 and 17.253.144.10) for apple.com when I run the code in my home WiFi network, but in my companies WiFi network I get only the IPv4 address. Right now I do not know why that is.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the following Swift code to get DNS resolution for a website. One method uses `CFHostStartInfoResolution` whereas other one uses `gethostbyname`.

Both these APIs support all/multiple IP address resolution.

```
private func urlToIP_cfHostResolution(_ url: String) -> [String] {

    var ipList: [String] = []

    let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,url as CFString).takeRetainedValue()

    CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .addresses, nil)

    var success: DarwinBoolean = false

    if let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success)?.takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray? {

        for case let theAddress as NSData in addresses {

            var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

            if getnameinfo(theAddress.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
                       &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {

                ipList.append(String(cString: hostname))
            }    
        }
    }

    return ipList
}
```

This method returns `["151.101.129.69", "151.101.1.69", "151.101.193.69", "151.101.65.69"]` for `www.stackoverflow.com`

```
private func urlToIP_gethostbyname(_ url: URL) -> [String] {

    var ipList: [String] = []

    guard let hostname = url.host else {

        return ipList
    }

    guard let host = hostname.withCString({gethostbyname($0)}) else {

        return ipList
    }

    guard host.pointee.h_length > 0 else {

        return ipList
    }

    var index = 0

    while host.pointee.h_addr_list[index] != nil {

        var addr: in_addr = in_addr()

        memcpy(&addr.s_addr, host.pointee.h_addr_list[index], Int(host.pointee.h_length))

        guard let remoteIPAsC = inet_ntoa(addr) else {

            return ipList
        }

        ipList.append(String.init(cString: remoteIPAsC))

        index += 1
    }

    return ipList
}
```

This method also returns `["151.101.129.69", "151.101.1.69", "151.101.193.69", "151.101.65.69"]` for `www.stackoverflow.com`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A number of the answers are using the deprecated `bytes` to retrieve the `sockaddr` to supply to `getnameinfo`. We’d use `address.withUnsafeBytes` now. For example, in Swift 5:

```
/// Returns the string representation of the supplied address.
///
/// - parameter address: Contains a `(struct sockaddr)` with the address to render.
///
/// - returns: A string representation of that address.

func stringRepresentation(forAddress address: Data) -> String? {
    address.withUnsafeBytes { pointer in
        var hostStr = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

        let result = getnameinfo(
            pointer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self),
            socklen_t(address.count),
            &hostStr,
            socklen_t(hostStr.count),
            nil,
            0,
            NI_NUMERICHOST
        )
        guard result == 0 else { return nil }
        return String(cString: hostStr)
    }
}
```