# NetService getting proper Inet type while debugging but not working from archived IPA

Tags: swift, nsnetservice, networkextension

I am working with netsevices and using below function to Get IPV4 and IPV6 address.Getting Proper addresses while debugging or simple IPA file. But AFTER ARCHIVING I do not get proper INET Type.

This is strange issue.

```
func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
        if let addresses = sender.addresses, addresses.count > 0 {
            for address in addresses {
                let data = address as NSData
                
                let inetAddress: sockaddr_in = data.castToCPointer()
                if inetAddress.sin_family == __uint8_t(AF_INET) {
                    if let ip = String(cString: inet_ntoa(inetAddress.sin_addr), encoding: .ascii) {
                        // IPv4
                        bonjourIP = ip
                    }
                } else if inetAddress.sin_family == __uint8_t(AF_INET6) {
                    let inetAddress6: sockaddr_in6 = data.castToCPointer()
                    let ipStringBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))
                    var addr = inetAddress6.sin6_addr
                    
                    if let ipString = inet_ntop(Int32(inetAddress6.sin6_family), &addr, ipStringBuffer, __uint32_t(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN)) {
                        if let ip = String(cString: ipString, encoding: .ascii) {
                            // IPv6
                            bonjourIP = ip
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ipStringBuffer.deallocate(capacity: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it working for IPv6? and not working properly for IPv4? right?

Comment: It is not working for BOTH,While build is archived. Otherwise it works.@aBilal17

Comment: Where does the `castToCPointer()` method come from?

Comment: Better use `getnameinfo()` to get the IP address as a string, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25891306/1187415 for an example.